# Combine percentage with pixels

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to combine percentage with pixels in css?
For example, I want a div width to be 50% + 10px.

Javascript / Jquery plugin are acceptable solutions.
But something that work globally, and not require to write additional code for any additional block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 'hard' problem in CSS, that only recently has any fix. The fix in CSS is to use the `calc` method, as demoed here:

http://dabblet.com/gist/3966215

Be aware that dabblet adds vendor prefixes automatically, so you need to use:

```
-webkit-calc()
-moz-calc()
-ms-calc()
-o-calc()
calc()
```

Browser support is OKish, http://caniuse.com/#search=calc - in short it's IE9 and up, and not in Opera.

As far as I know there isn't any polyfill in JS to make this work in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
div { width: calc(50% + 10px); }
```

Does not work prior to IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help

CSS

```
#testWrapper {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #aaa;
} 

.test {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}​
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  window.calcWidth = function(el, property, data){
    $(el).css(property, data);
      alert($(el).width());
  }

  calcWidth('.test', 'width', '+=50px');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="testWrapper">
    <div class="test">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lacus urna, congue eu cursus nec, aliquet non lorem. Sed ullamcorper tempus enim, a vulputate dui suscipit vulputate.
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/HBEw8/1/) :)

But honestly i'd use those css way that other guys showed. There are definitely a few jQuery plugins that help to make it crossbrowser...

Also You could do it with binding on resize..but it's also not good way

Comment: It helps a bit, but I was looking for something that can work globally without adding extra javascript code for any additional block. The css calc function is just what I need, the only problem is the cross-browser support. - Voted for your answer anyway, thanks.